# How to customize a brief table of contents generated from tocloft and shorttoc into one page?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft, shorttoc

I am writing a book with over 20 chapters using LaTex. I generated the detailed Table of Contents with the package tocloft, and a brief TOC with shorttoc. Right now, the brief TOC has two pages but I really like it to be one page long. Commands from tocloft can only control some of the features in the brief TOC. I have my sample code attached at the end. Specifically, my questions are as follows. I greatly appreciate any help you have. -- Edwin

Question 1: How can I adjust the line spaces in the brief TOC only so it can be one page long?

Question 2: How can I adjust the space before and after the title of "Brief Contents?"

Question 3: How can I remove the entry of "Contents" from the brief TOC only?

---- sample code -----------------

```
\documentclass{book}

% 1. load two packges
\usepackage[tight]{shorttoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% 2. add a line below part title in TOC
\makeatletter  
    \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{0em}
    \renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\par\vskip-2ex\hrulefill\par}
\makeatother

% 3. adjust vertical space in TOC
\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{0pt} % change space before TOC title
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}  % change space after  TOC title
\setlength\cftbeforepartskip{16pt}  % change space before part
\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{8pt}   % change space before chapter
%\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{1pt}   % change space before section
%\setlength\cftparskip{-2pt}        % distance between paragraphs/entry; default 0


\begin{document}

% 4. add brief TOC
\clearpage \phantomsection 
\shorttoc{Brief Contents}{0}

% 5. add detailed TOC
\clearpage \phantomsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents} % add a link for Contents in TOC 
\tableofcontents


\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 3}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 4}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 5}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 6}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 7}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 8}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't know how to do it using `shorttoc`, but here's one possibility using the powerful [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter  
    \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{0em}
    \renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\par\vskip-2ex\hrulefill\par}
\makeatother

\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{0pt} % change space before TOC title
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}  % change space after  TOC title
\setlength\cftbeforepartskip{16pt}  % change space before part
\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{8pt}   % change space before chapter


\titlecontents{schapter}
  [27pt]
  {\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{27pt}}
  {\hspace*{-27pt}}
  {\titlerule*[100pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{spart}
  [27pt]
  {\large\bfseries\vskip5pt}
  {\contentslabel{27pt}}
  {\hspace*{-27pt}}
  {\titlerule*[100pc]{.}\contentspage}[\vskip-2ex\hrulefill{\\*[-1.8ex]}]


\begin{document}

\startcontents[short]

\clearpage 
\phantomsection
\printcontents[short]{s}{-1}{%
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}%
  \noindent{\Huge\bfseries Brief Contents}\par\bigskip%
}

\clearpage 
\phantomsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\addtocontents{toc}{}

\stopcontents[short]

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents} % add a link for Contents in TOC 
\tableofcontents


\resumecontents[short]

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 3}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 4}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 5}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 6}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 7}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\part{Part 8}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter} \section{Test Section} \section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToCs showing the requested features:

[image]